# Библиотека Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel не содержит некоторые члены классов

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

Сегодня столкнулся с такой проблемой: при использовании библиотеки классов Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel , не могу найти некоторые её члены, к примеру раньше при добавлении книги использовал следующий способ:

```
Application excelApp = new Application();
excelApp.Workbooks.Add();   // Добавление книги
excelApp.Visible = true;    // Отображение окна приложения
```

теперь, при добавлении книги, Workbooks отсутствует, но появился метод get_Workbooks(),

 т.е. уже добавление книги выглядит следующим образом:

```
excelApp.get_Workbooks().Add();
```

Cвойство Visible вообще отсутствует и интуитивно найти похожее пока не смог. 

 Теперь момент, идентичная библиотека используется в другом приложении, оба проекта реализован на платформе .net 4.0, использую идентичный код программы и т.д.

 Перехожу по ссылкам "Application" (через F12) и вижу, что версии библиотек одинаковые, идентификаторы одинаковые, но списки членов разные!..

 Почему так происходит???

 И ещё, не могу найти документацию для использования этой изменённой библиотеки с которой сейчас имею дело.

Comment: Скорее всего вы используете не ту версию библиотеки. Для работы с .XLSX рекомендую использовать что нибудь другое, например [это](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus)

Comment: @pasha goroshko, эта же версия библиотеки используется в другой программе, и в ней она работает отлично и я не понимаю, в чём может быть причина таких резких в ней изменений..

Comment: осмелюсь предложить Вам проверить все ссылки и using-и в коде - мне кажется Вы создали какой-то другой, похожий класс - мне не удалось воспроизвести Вашу ошибку